# Why do we regard $W^\pm$ as physical fields but not $W^1$ and $W^2$?

Tags: gauge-theory, electroweak

When expanding the electroweak Lagrangian, we obtain terms like

$$
\mathcal L = \frac{g}{2}(\bar e_L (W^1_\mu + iW^2_\mu)\gamma^\mu \nu_L + \bar \nu_L (W^1_\mu -iW^2_\mu )\gamma^\mu e_L)+ \dots
$$

and then redefine the fields as $W^\pm =W^1_\mu \mp iW^2_\mu$.

It seems that we don't want two different gauge fields interacting with the same fermions, but I don't know why is this. Shouldn't any linear combination be on the same footing? Although I guess some eigenstates are phenomenologically more convenient.

Answer (score 4):

It's not that we don't want two different gauge fields interacting with the same fermions, it's that you can clearly see from this Lagrangian that if an antineutrino interacts with an electron, they can produce a particle given by $W^- =W^1_\mu + iW^2_\mu$.  The two gauge bosons that are produced are coherent, so they behave as a single particle.  Since there are no terms in the Lagrangian that couple to only $W^1_\mu$ or $W^2_\mu$, there is no process in nature that will produce just one of them, so it is more convenient to redefine the fields in terms of single particles that are actually produced.

Comment: Is the mixing of the EM potential and the $W^3$ through the Weinberg angle because of the same reason?

Comment: jinawee: yes, exactly